# Yii CGridView hyperlink open in new tab

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have made one column of my yii CGridview as a hyperlink. But on clicking it, it opens link address within the same tab. How can I open the link address in a new tab ?

```
array(
    'header'=>'Name',
    'name'  => 'name',
    'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->name, $data->site_url)',
    'type'  => 'raw',
),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `target` attribute as `_blank` for the link (`<a>`) that will be generated:

```
<a href="some_url" target="_blank">Foo</a>
```

With [`CHtml::link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail) :

```
'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->name, $data->site_url, array("target"=>"_blank"))',
```

The last parameter to `CHtml::link()` (and most other html helpers in CHtml class), is htmlOptions, which is supposed to be an associative array with html attributes as keys and their values as values:

```
array(
    "target"=>"_blank",
    "class"=>"my-css-class",
    // ... any other html attribute ..
)
```

Comment: @sarah this works perfectly fine, please read the questions correctly before jumping to conclusions(and incorrect down voting)! the answers are both correct for their respective questions.

Comment: @sarah, oh, in that case please ask and i shall help out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new-tab-link in value field,I create the link by hand:

here's the code:

```
'value'=>'<a target=_blank href='.Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/index', array('id'=>$model->id)).'>Link</a>'
```