# Yii: CGridView - open a link in new window

Tags: yii, hyperlink, cgridview

I have big problems in generating a button in CGridView that opens a page in a new browser window. This is the code, I use:

```
'preview' => array(
  'value' => 'CHtml::link("test", array("classified/preview", "id"=>$data->id), array("target"=>"_blank"))',
  'header' => 'Name',
  'name' => 'name',
  'type' => 'raw',
),
```

The generated link looks like this:

```
http://localhost/fotomarkt/index.php?r=classified/listmine#
```

So the link is wrong and the "target=_blank" is ignored.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737536/yii-cgridview-hyperlink-open-in-new-tab) with bool.dev's good answer, but somehow, it doesn't work for me...

I guess, it's something stupid, which I simply don't see...

Comment: Is this in your CButtonColumn?

Comment: remove the `type=>raw`

Comment: The link is wrong? What link do you expect to show up?

Comment: Also, please post your complete CGridView code

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't answer so fast - yes, it was CButtonColumn and not CGridColumn, which I mixed up. The question is answered, thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above is fine for a [`CGridColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn). However, it looks like you are using a [`CButtonColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn). The code below should suffice.

```
'preview' => array(
    'url' => 'array("classified/preview", "id"=>$data->id)',
    'label'=>'test',
    'options'=>array("target"=>"_blank"),
),
```

Also if you require a column in which each cell contains a single link **only**, a [`CLinkColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn) would be more suited than a CGridColumn.

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed is the solution. :-)
I mixed up CGridColumn and CButtonColumn - now it perfectly works!